# How to imitate rotation on another object precisely in edit mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]

Hello, I want Object b) to have the exact same rotation as object a in edit mode. But toggling "N" doesn't have options for rotation angle. What is the most precise way to rotate my b) object in edit mode?

Best

Comment: if you are in Edit mode, you won't rotate the object but the mesh inside the object. Do you want to align your mesh with some faces of the object A's mesh? It's not clear...

Comment: Oh no, I want to rotate the mesh to use it as a cutter on the roof left, but I wanted B) lenght to be A)'s lenght to do it in one cut. The problem there is also that I have to turn the mesh ob B) into a seperate object/layer. Is that even possible?

Comment: it's a bit confusing, are these 2 meshes inside the same object? You can separate a mesh and create a new object with it: select it with L and press P > Separate

Comment: If A and B are meshes then yes, they are in the same Object "cube" in the scene collection, or in the same scene. P was the key that made things easier a whole lot